# Is there a way to automatically trigger submit without pressing the submit button?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to submit a form automatically without the need to press the submit button. What I'm trying to achieve is, a page gets the information, processes that information and then redirects it to the other page.

My approach on the redirection so far:-

```
<form action='<?php echo $url;?>' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='hiddenInfo' value='<?php echo $myInfo;?>'/>
</form>
<?php
header("Location:$url");
```

I know the above code does not work but I'm just trying to show what my approach is. Is it even possible to automatically submit the data without any event handler.

So far I'm trying to avoid the `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.mysite.com/info/"/>`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can submit it with javascript. but not with php. You should bind the input to submit to your page via ajax when page is loaded

Comment: Are you saying you don't even need a user to provide entries (which is what your form above looks like? Then why even write content to the browser? Can't you do everything in Php? Process some data coming in via GET or POST, then (assuming you still need to), redirect to page x?

Comment: @RPM I will try that and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @EdSF It's a bit complicated. The data really comes from user, I manipulate that data, store it in a hidden value and send it back to user for viewing/editing/manipulation etc.

Comment: @RPM I tried the jquery approach and it worked but your method made sense too. And I think that's exactly what jquery does too. Checks when the page is loaded and binds the input to submit with .submit. Thank you for helping me understand this. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Couldn't you just use [$().submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) on document ready?

```
$(function() { $("form").submit(); });
```

or:

```
$(function() { $("#formid").submit(); });
```

or:

```
$(function() { $("form:first").submit(); });
```

Comment: I thought about that but was under the impression that `$().submit` waited for the event to occur, which was not what I wanted. But I'll take a look at it again.

Comment: Awesome!! it worked. Thank you so much!! I spent almost 4 hours thinking that this method will not work and trying other stupid things. -_-

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='<?php echo $url;?>' method='post' id="myform">
    <input type='hidden' name='hiddenInfo' value='<?php echo $myInfo;?>'/>
</form>
$(function() { $("#myform").submit(); });
```

Try this, may have more than one form so put some id in that form..

Comment: It worked!! Wow, if only I had known it was this simple. Tried all kind of other stuff. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yonjan shrestha sathi, hehe ma ni nepali nai ho

Comment: Hello, my fellow countryman. I'm new here so thanks for guiding me!! Also, it's yojan not yonjan. :)

Answer (score 0):

IF you are php programmer then you might not want any javascript answer. the best solution to this is

1.USE A PROXY like paros or HTTP analyser they will give u the insight how site's form is structued

2.notE down the forms POST OR GET VALUE SYNTAX FROM THE HTTP analyzer or paros proxy.

read this tutorial it is the best tutorial out there

http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-submit.html

4.change the content of $_post or $_get according to their structure which you have noted down in

paros or HTTP analyser